# Extending the width of the parent container to accommodate the child's width

Tags: html, css

Please check this example that I made:

**HTML:**

```
<body class="pcon">
     <div class="ccon">
     </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.pcon{
    border:solid;width:100%;background-color:pink;
}

.ccon{
    width:2000px;height:300px;background-color:green;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fpv3tfu6/4/

This is for the site that I am making, I have a div with a fixed size that might not be accommodated by the parent div if the user decided to resize the window, since I am using a width of 100% and my div has a fixed size of `1200px` and if the user decided to resize the window, the same scenario happens since the parent will have to adapt to the new width.

To emulate what the scenario is, I have a parent div with 100% on width and it has a child with a div width of `2000px`. As we see, the border doesn't completely "cover" the green box. What should i do to make the parent's border contain the div with a bigger size due to possible resizing?

The solution that I thought of is to use `min-width` (since the parent's width will be bigger than the pre-specified div's width).

Comment: Maybe because of the typo width = 100%. It should be `width: 100%`

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you really want here. The child will overflow its parent if the fixed width is higher. Use `width: auto` for occupying the full width of the parent.

Comment: that's not ti issue. The parent will always have 100%, and if the window size is smaller than that the child width, then the child will not fit. You can go the other way, set fixed width to the parent and add 100% to the child, but I don't know your constraints if you could do this

Comment: Problem is that, when the page first loads, the parent's div will be bigger than the child but if i decided to resize the window, my top menu bar with 100% width won't match my content's with a now wider width since it's fixed and It will be the same scenario as above.. I was able to fix it by defining the `min-width` that matches the child's width.